# How to find the statistics of a vector? Max/Min, mode, median, mean

Tags: c++, vector

My task is to ask the user for a minimum and maximum x value. I then use the extremes to calculate 20 values in between those extremes. I have to display the x value and it's f(x) value onto a table. I then have to find statistics on the f(x) values, like min and max, mean, mode, and median. I am not familiar enough with vectors to find these statistics. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code so far...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double xmin, xmax;
   const int POINTS = 20;
   const double PI = 3.1416;
   double increments;
   int counter = 0;

   vector<vector<float> > values;

   cout << "Enter in a value for the minimum x value: ";
   cin >> xmin;
   cout << "Enter in a value for the maximum x value: ";
   cin >> xmax;

   increments = (abs(xmin) + xmax) / POINTS;

   double x = xmin + increments * counter;
   double min = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x);
   double max = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x);

   cout << setw(15) << "x |" << setw(15) << "f(x)" << endl;
   cout << setw(32) << setfill('-') << " " << endl;
   cout << setfill(' ');
   vector<float> auxiliar;

   while (x <= xmax)
   {
      auxiliar.resize(2);
      auxiliar[0] = x;
      auxiliar[1] = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x);

      values.push_back(auxiliar);
      auxiliar.clear();

      if (0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x) > max)
         max = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x);
      if (0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x) < min)
         min = 0.0572 * cos(4.667 * x) + 0.0218 * PI * cos(12.22 * x);
      counter++;
      x = xmin + increments * counter;

   }

   for(vector<float> i:values)
     cout << fixed << showpos << setw(15) << setprecision(2) << i[0] <<         setw(15) << setprecision(4) << i[1] << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You took off your answer

Comment: If we show you how to get access to the elements of the vector, do you know how to use them to calculate min, max, etc.?

Comment: I know how to sort them from lowest to highest using the std::sort, and the minimum would be the first element, and the maximum would be the n-1 element.

Comment: You don't have to explain how to do it, I just want to know whether you know how, so that I'll know what you *don't* want help with. Now how about the **etc.** I mentioned, the other statistics?

Comment: I am not sure about the mode, mean and median

Comment: _"I am not familiar enough with vectors to find these statistics."_ Do you mean that you are familiar with `std::vector`, but you don't know how to calculate these statistics?

Comment: No, I don't know how to implement it through programming. Not much experience. I do know what they are. I haven't had much experience with arrays, and not much with vectors either. I actually asked for help and they told me to use vectors, and the code is what I came up with.

Comment: I initially wanted to use just a one dimensional array, because I know how to get those mean, min/max, range.

Comment: **If we show you how to get access to the elements of the vector, do you know how to use them to calculate the statistics?**

Comment: If I have trouble I could just ask for help

Answer (score 0):

Take `vector<int>` for example. A crude but effective way to get the elements is like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i)
{
  int n = vec[i];
  ...
}
```

Now `vector<vector<int>>`:

```
for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i)
  for(int j=0; j<vec[i].size(); ++j)
  {
    int n = vec[i][j];
    ...
  }
```